# Jquery ui tabs manipulation

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 3 jquery ui tabs in my page. For each tab I call some functions.

$( "#tabs" ).tabs({

```
    select: function(event, ui) {
            var text = ui.tab.text;
            $("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").empty();
            switch(text){
                case 'tab1':
                    //function
                    break;
                case 'tab2':
                    //function
                    break;
                case 'tab3':
                    //function
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

In some cases, I must to open tab2, for example, through a button from #tab1 div, but with a different logic. From this I use:

```
$("#tab2").html("text tab2");
$("#tabs" ).tabs("select", 1);
```

This operation add 'text tab2' to #tab2 block, but 'tabs(select, 1)' event open the second tab and execute the function from switch case 'tab2' described above.

How I can add my text in the tab and open it, without using option 'select'?

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't find any solutions for this problem, but I resolved it through another method,disabling the 'select case tab2 functions' by a cookie variable send to tab.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
        var text = ui.tab.text;
        var type = "";
        $("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").empty();
        var cook = $(this).tabs("option", "cookie");
        if(cook){
            type = cook.type;
        }
        switch(text){
            case 'tab1':
                //function
                break;
            case 'tab2':
                if(type!='extern'){
                      //function
                }
                break;
            case 'tab3':
                //function
                break;
        }
        //remove the cookie
        $(this).tabs({cookie: {type: ""}});
    }
});
```

To open the tab by another link, using 'selected' option without passing through case 'tab2':

```
$("#tab2").html("text tab2");
$("#tabs" ).tabs({cookie: {type: "extern"}});
$("#tabs" ).tabs("select", 1);
```